# Average positive numbers in a row

Tags: python, math, numpy, matrix

I have a numpy matrix, and each row has a combination of positive and negative numbers.

I want to create a new vector, that gives me the average of all the positive numbers in a row in the matrix.

For instance, if this is the matrix:

```
[[1 2 3 -1]

[2 5 -6 5]]
```

I want to create the vector with the values:

```
[[2]

[4]]
```

What's the fastest way to do so?

There will always be positive numbers.

Comment: What if there are no positive numbers in a row? What must be the average then?

Comment: @Divakar There will always be positive numbers.

Comment: Also, are you considering `0` as a positive number? Could there be zeros in the input array?

Comment: @Divakar Yes, zeroes are possible.

Comment: So, are you considering 0 as a positive number?

Comment: @j.doe: As a suggestion you should avoid terms like "positive" or "negative". Always use "strictly positive" or "not negative" as this avoids any ambiguity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's guaranteed to have at least one positive number `(>=0)` per row, you could convert the `negative numbers (excluding 0)` to `NaNs` with [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and then use [`np.nanmean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) along the rows, like so -

```
np.nanmean(np.where(A>=0,A,np.nan),axis=1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [69]: A
Out[69]: 
array([[ 2,  3, -6, -6, -4],
       [-5, -6, -1, -1,  3],
       [-8,  5, -7, -9, -9],
       [-3,  0,  7, -5, -6]])

In [70]: np.nanmean(np.where(A>=0,A,np.nan),axis=1)
Out[70]: array([ 2.5,  3. ,  5. ,  3.5])
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be

- select all non-negative
- compute explicitly the mean as sum/count

In code:

```
notneg = x >= 0
result = (x * notneg).sum(1) / notneg.sum(1)
```